# Programming ESP32 with this FTDI adapter

Tags: esp32

I have an FTDI adapter that has 6 pins and want to upload to a ESP32 Wroom32D module without onboard buttons

```
VCC
GND
TXD
RXD
RTS
CTS
```

Is it possible to program an ESP32 and autoreboot using these pins?
If so what is the best way to lay it out

Comment: This is a Q&A site. Please ask a question, as currently there is nothing to answer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done. ESP32 programming needs 3 control signal inputs to the ESP32.

`boot`, `~enable`, and `RxD`

your FT232 only has 2 outputs `TxD` and `RTS`

You'll need a third output from the FT232,
Perhaps you can solder a wire to the `DTR` pin of the chip.

Then you can use transistors, to map the `TXD` and `DTR` outputs onto the `boot` and `~enable` pins. You can get the ESP-Prog, schematic from Espressif and copy that part.

Comment: Thanks I'lll invest in an esp prog

Comment: the circuit needed is fairly simple, but buying one is certainly a cheaper option for a professional.

Comment: I dont want to have a programming circuit built into the board as it will mostly be initial setup and then it will be updated OTA

Comment: it could be a module soldered to the FT232,

Answer (score 0):

[image: Bare_bone ESP32]

Hold down D0 while uploading. Release after. Reboot.

Comment: The OP clearly says "without onboard buttons". Unless you are suggesting some kind of programming jig this is not helpful. If you do suggest a jig then please, clearly say so

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/346880)

Answer (score 0):

Would "outboard buttons" work for you? You can add a connector or just pads for pogo pins to your board with all required signals, then use simple external programming circuit with two buttons and FTDI. This would be even cheaper than esp prog and just as good for one-time initial programming.